# Json and ListViev

Tags: json, listview

I have Code in OnPostExecute

```
                    JSONArray friend = json.getJSONArray("users");
                    ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < friend.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject att = (JSONObject) friend.getJSONObject(i);

                        String res = att.getString("username");
                        item.add(res);

                    }


                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
                    //Assign adapter to List
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

And I Know that there is some kind of variable type mismatch but i dont know how to fix it. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: i mean with variable item that o should put into listView

Comment: thanks for awesome answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
```

Thanks to those idio... kind people who gave me -2 :)